# to list the operations that belong to a database in mysql - (SHOW PROCESSLIST)

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I would like to list the processes in Mysql. I have multiple databases for in my connection. When I say Show process list, the processes of all databases come. How do I view processes for a single database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for the [information_schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/processlist-table.html). That's where `SHOW PROCESSLIST` gets its information.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE DB = DATABASE()
```

Of course, the function `DATABASE()` returns the current database, as chosen by `USE DATABASE` or by your login default database.

If for some reason that is not set, and you know the name of your database, try this.

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE DB = 'my_database_name'
```

Comment: Notice the documentation saids this about the DB column *"The default database, if one is selected; otherwise NULL. "*   seams it might only work if you use `USE database` command.  So i think queries like `SELECT * FROM database.table` will not work as expected or across database subqueries/join's for that matter.